# what defines an object length in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

```
 function CookieStorage(maxage, path) { // Arguments specify lifetime and scope
// Get an object that holds all cookies
var cookies = (function() { // The getCookies() function shown earlier
var cookies = {}; // The object we will return
var all = document.cookie; // Get all cookies in one big string

if (all === "") // If the property is the empty string
    return cookies; // return an empty object
    var list = all.split("; "); // Split into individual name=value pairs
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { // For each cookie
        var cookie = list[i];
        var p = cookie.indexOf("="); // Find the first = sign
        var name = cookie.substring(0,p); // Get cookie name
        var value = cookie.substring(p+1); // Get cookie value
        value = decodeURIComponent(value); // Decode the value
        cookies[name] = value; // Store name and value
    }
    return cookies;
}());

// Collect the cookie names in an array
var keys = [];
for(var key in cookies) keys.push(key);
// Now define the public properties and methods of the Storage API
// The number of stored cookies
**this.length = keys.length;**
// Return the name of the nth cookie, or null if n is out of range

this.key = function(n) {
if (n < 0 || n >= keys.length) return null;
return keys[n];
};

// Return the value of the named cookie, or null.
this.getItem = function(name) { return cookies[name] || null; };

**// Store a value
this.setItem = function(key, value) {
    if (!(key in cookies)) { // If no existing cookie with this name
        keys.push(key); // Add key to the array of keys
        this.length++; // And increment the length
    }**

    // Store this name/value pair in the set of cookies.
    cookies[key] = value;

    // Now actually set the cookie.
    // First encode value and create a name=encoded-value string
    var cookie = key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);

    // Add cookie attributes to that string
    if (maxage) cookie += "; max-age=" + maxage;
    if (path) cookie += "; path=" + path;

    // Set the cookie through the magic document.cookie property
    document.cookie = cookie;
};
```

Hello guys, I found this piece of code in a book that I'm reading, and I saw this one line that made no sense to me:

```
**// Store a value
this.setItem = function(key, value) {
    if (!(key in cookies)) { // If no existing cookie with this name
        keys.push(key); // Add key to the array of keys
        this.length++; // And increment the length
    }**
```

If the object's that we're currently in length property has already been defined by previous line of code (**this.length = keys.length;**)
Why do we need to increment its length by this.length++ ??
Isn't keys.push(key) enough?

**EDIT**:

Thanks to all who answered.
After staring at this code for a couple of minutes, i figured out that the first length declaration was relevant only for that "phase" in scripts time.
this.length = keys.length 
means that this objects length is equal to the **current** length of key array.

Later on, when we added another element to key array, it's length increased, this why we must tell it to our object by increasing its own value this time (**this.length++;**)

Comment: Objects have no length, you can try `Object.keys(obj).length`. Also, good indentation and less comments would help to read your code better.

Comment: the two lines of code that set the length run at different times. The `this.length = keys.length` is the initialization of the plain object's `.length`, and the `this.length++` is in another function that runs when a new item is added. If your code had fewer comments and better indentation, this would be easier to see.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough, but if you want to use this function from outside code then you don't have access to the internal `values` array, so this is a convenience property to get the length.

You can replace it with a getter like this and skip updating it manually each time:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "length", {
    get: function() {
        return keys.length;
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** As @zzzzBov noted in his comment, IE8 and below don't support getters yet.

Comment: ...in modern browsers. Of course, this will fail in IE, so it won't be useful for another couple years when everyone can finally cross IE8 off the list.

Comment: @zzzzBov Damn compatibility :)

Comment: Solution: if we stop supporting IE8 it will die faster; not selling it to clients unless they really need it (because they asked for it), and obviously charge the extra fee for "older browser support". We can't just expect every answer on SO to be compatible with IE8,  nor expect people to add the clause every single time.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setItem = function(key, value) {
    if (!(key in cookies)) { // If no existing cookie with this name
        keys.push(key); // Add key to the array of keys
        this.length++; // And increment the length
    }
    ...
};
```

If you look at just this code, you'll notice that it's declaring a function. The code within this function will execute when `setItem` is called on the instance of `CookieStorage`.

The previous line is called when a `CookieStorage` instance is being created. The purpose of incrementing the length is to produce a public API for the length of the privately stored array.

Answer (score 0):

For your firtst question:
Basically It's defines the number of the parameters that the function gets only if you Asking for the function Length for example:
`CookieStorage.length`

```
function a() {}
function b(a, b) {}
function c(a,b,c) {}

console.log(a.length); //output 0
console.log(b.length); //output 2
console.log(c.length); //output 3
```

for the `this.length` question:
Well, this.length is the property that hold the `keys.length`.
so when you set a new item to the keys array it's update the length property with the new length. so you can use it with:

```
var cookies = new CookieStorage();
cookies.setItem("test","test");
cookies.length //output 1
```

Comment: +1 I'm not sure why this was down-voted; it's still applicable

Comment: @naomik: Probably because it has nothing to do with the question. So why did you upvote it?

Comment: "What defines an object length?" Well for a function, an object in JavaScript, `length` is the number of args the function accepts. While this answer isn't complete, it's certainly answers the question for function objects. For what it's worth, this is also known as [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity)

Comment: @naomik: Yes, if you only look at the title, and if you only consider one type of object, then sure. If you bother to... you know... read the question, you'll see that the `.length` being asked about has nothing to do with a function's length.

Answer (score 0):

It is my first answer. Hope it helps.

Looks like this.length does not mean the cookie array's length, isn't it?
Yes, if it uses the push() function, the array's length will definitely increment by one.
You do not have to do it manually.

Unless, this.length mean something else.